# Open raster referenced in attribute column of vector layer

Tags: qgis, raster, pyqgis

I have a polygon layer. One of the columns holds an absolute path to a (georeferenced) raster. Is there a way to (programmatically) open this raster in QGIS and add it to the map canvas?

Comment: yes, i added it to the original question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will add the first raster (in my example the only one) from the vector layers attribute table:

```
import os 
vector_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('vl')[0] #Change
field_with_path = 'abspath' #Change

rasterpath = [f[field_with_path] for f in vector_layer.getFeatures()][0] #[0] for the first feature
rlayer = iface.addRasterLayer(rasterpath,os.path.basename(rasterpath)[:-4],"gdal")
```

[image]

Comment: that's great, thank you! I see, i need to get more into python!